# How can I show on my keyboard only numbers with qt

Tags: qt, qml, virtual-keyboard

I'm using Qt Quick Virtual Keyboard on my project and when I click on an object I want to show the keyboard but just the numbers. How can I do that?

This is what I'm trying to do

[image: just showing the numeric keyboard like this]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`Qt.ImhFormattedNumbersOnly`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-textinput.html#inputMethodHints-prop) which allows only number input. This includes also decimal point and minus sign.

Example usage:

```
TextField {
    id: your_id

    placeholderText: qsTr("სახელი")

    inputMethodHints: Qt.ImhFormattedNumbersOnly
}
```