# QtVirtualKeyboard how to set default input method?

Tags: qt, qml, qtvirtualkeyboard

When the keyboard opens, the default layer is shown with letters

[image]

How to do that by default shown a layer with numbers?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I show on my keyboard only numbers with qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46193913/how-can-i-show-on-my-keyboard-only-numbers-with-qt)

Comment: I want a regular keyboard with letters to be available, but when opening it was shown a layer with numbers. In that answer it is proposed to output only a layer with numbers

Comment: Reading your question I interpret it asking how to get numbers only mode instead of regular mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt virtual keyboard follows [inputMethodHints](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-textinput.html#inputMethodHints-prop). So, you can e.g. create a form with `TextField` QML types and set different `inputMethodHints` for different fields like name, phone number, pin code etc. When you change the field keyboard changes its mode. You can set `Qt.ImhDigitsOnly` restrictive mode for pin code field to only accept numbers turning keyboard to a keypad.

If your keyboard opens with a number layout in a specific text input field it sounds like `Qt.ImhPreferNumbers` or something like that is set to inputMethodHints. You could try to figure out who sets the value and test to reset by setting it explicitly to `Qt.ImhNone`.